# How to give classpath value in properties file to variable

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I am looking for a correct way for giving classpath value to a variable in properties file

```
logging.file=classpath:logs/server.log
```

So that when I run my project the log file gets created in the classpath with the folder name log.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Classpath may contain various folders (so how to choose one of them?) plus jars in which you cannot create anything. I guess it is not a very good idea to create something 'on a classpath'. You'd better put your log at some file system directory:

```
logging.file=/some/external/directory/server.log
```

Answer (score 0):

> So that when I run my project the log file gets created in the
>   classpath with the folder name log.

You want to create the log file in the classpath of the application ?
It doesn't make sense. 
Classpath doesn't serve this purpose.

1) Your application will be finally started from a JAR or a WAR. You want put the file in it??

2) You want to able to retrieve the log file in a place where you know that you will retrieve it. Putting it in a place where it may be removed as you repackage again the application doesn't make sense either.

The log file should of course be outside of the application.
For example :

```
logging.file=logs/my-app/server.log
```